# How to make Pythontex work with arara on Vim Latex-Suite?

Tags: compiling, python, arara, vim-latex, pythontex

I'm trying to use Pythontex on Vim Latex-suite, compiling with arara 3.

I've tried the method that Uwe Ziegenhagen proposed here : 
[Arara rule for Pythontex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357881/arara-rule-for-pythontex][1])

I put exactly the same pythontex.yaml file in the right directory, i have Pythontex installed in my texmf...
But when i try this :

```
% arara: lualatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode, options: "-file-line-error-style"}
% arara: pythontex
% arara: lualatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode, options: "-file-line-error-style"}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
a=5
print(a)
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

nothing happens...
I precise that compiling with arara is ok otherwise (i use it to compile with luacode or to generate bibliographies...).

Any idea ??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The document works fine. Did you try it on the command line, without arara?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure to understand... I've modified my texrc in order to have a pdf output, and changed the CompileRule_pdf in TexLet g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'arara -v $*' so i can compile with my arara parameters juste with the \ll command

Comment: I asked if you could run the compilation commands in a terminal and obtain the expected result. If this is the case (for me, it is), this would imply that `pythontex` is correctly installed on your computer and the question would remain an arara configuration problem. Without this info, there is still doubt about where the issue lies.

Comment: Ok. The result of the pythontex compilation in my terminal is " This is PythonTeX 0.16
* PythonTeX error
    The version of the PythonTeX scripts does not match the last code
    saved by the document--run LaTeX to create an updated version.
" so i guess pythontex is actually the problem...?

Comment: In my case, PythonTeX prints `This is PythonTeX 0.17

--------------------------------------------------
PythonTeX:  document - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)`. Not sure what happens on your side. Did you try it in a clean folder, with only the `.tex` file to begin with?

Comment: I have the pythontex package (in version 0.17) in my texmf, but it seems that it's not correctly installed...

Comment: How to install it correctly ? I executed the pythontex.ins, so i have one pythontex.sty in the texlive directory, and i also did it in my own texmf directory... But still, it doesn't work...

Comment: Which TeX distribution have you installed? You should be using a package manager to install and update pythontex rather than running any `.ins` file.