# Impossible to install pythontex... pythontex command always unavailable

Tags: compiling, arara, vim-latex, pythontex

I installed the pythontex package in my texmf directory, but still the command pythontex is not found when i write it in a terminal... And when i compile, \printpythontex returns ?? PythonTeX ??
Moreover, I think it's also installed in texlive (i installed texlive-full on linux) ??

Any idea to correct this ?

I'm trying to compile with pythontex with arara on Latex-suite, and all seems to work but pythontex...

To make pythontex work with arara, i made a pythontex.yaml file like it's proposed here : [Arara rule for Pythontex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357881/arara-rule-for-pythontex)

Comment: Are you compiling PythonTeX with arara? In arara, there is no compilation rule for PythonTeX (sadly). PythonTeX is distributed via full TeXlive (you should not need to install it manually).

Comment: Excuse me i didn't precise that i'm using the method that Uwe Ziegenhagen proposed here : Arara rule for Pythontex (i add the link in the post). So it should work...

Comment: Proper PythonTeX compilation procedure is `pdflatex` -> `pythontex` -> `pdflatex` (or any other latex). Did you do that?

Comment: Yes I put the lines % arara: lualatex and % arara: pythontex and then % arara: lualatex. I give more details on this post [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538042/how-to-make-pythontex-work-with-arara-on-vim-latex-suite?noredirect=1#comment1359389_538042]

Comment: the problem really seems to come from the pythontex installation...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. I still don't understand why i have pythontex 0.16, but i forgot to make the .py pythontex files executable...
Now it's ok, but if someone knows why i have the 0.16 version...
I find it strange because i did it from the CTAN package, but maybe i did something wrong, and just finally used the texlive-full version of pythontex, which should be 0.16 ?

Comment: which year texlive you have? The best approach for anyone new is to install full TeXlive and use its tlmgr updater than anything else ...

Comment: i installed texlive by the sudo apt-get install texlive-full command

Comment: Well, the Ubuntu packages are usually some-time behind the newest TeXlive, this is probably TeXlive 2018 (or 2017); and that is frozen (current updatable TeXlive is 2020). If you want newest PythonTeX since you are beginner, you should 100 % remove Ubuntu package and install current TeXlive from official web. Follow theyre install instructions.

Comment: Ok thanks for yout answer. Actually, all is ok now, all my files work (exercices generators with python, bibliographies etc). Would you highly recommend to reinstall texlive ? Are there very important updates ?

Comment: It highly depends on what you are using or want. If everything works as you want, no need to update. If you hit a problem, the first answer might be to reinstall and update ... Otherwise. Important updates also depends on packages you are using and if you are using LuaLaTeX. I deem as important updates of LuaLaTeX, PythonTeX and tcolorbox. These did have had important updates last year.